# Should interfaces use IEnumerable<MyObject> instead of MyObject[]

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable, enumeration

I have a lot of resharper warnings to change my parameters from a regular array to IEnumerable of the same type so it would change this:

```
 public Interface IGenerator
 {
       void Go(MyObject[] objects) 
 }
```

to this:

```
 public Interface IGenerator
 {
       void Go(IEumerable<MyObject> objects) 
 }
```

If I go and change all of these I then get other warning anytime I am calling .Where() on that inside my function, with the warning:

```
  Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable
```

I see this [error description](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Possible+multiple+enumeration+of+IEnumerable) but in this these are already arrays so not deffered queries.

so what is the recommended practice here?  should i just keep then as arrays or add .ToList() all over the place to remove the multiple enumerable error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Multiple enumeration" is not an error, it is a warning (a re-sharper warning, if I am not mistaken). You can ignore it if you know for sure that you pass "materialized" collections (as opposed to ones obtained lazily, e.g. through a function that `yield return`s its results).

- If changing the method signature to taking `IEumerable<MyObject>` makes sense because you want to pass results of various LINQ functions, then convert `ToList` inside your method.
- if you need to pass other collections in addition to arrays, use `ICollection<MyObject>` instead of `IEumerable<MyObject>`.
- If the conversion is purely for aesthetic reasons, i.e. you change the signature but keep passing arrays, you can ignore the warning altogether.

Comment: I always already have materialized arrays but my question in that case is it just clearer to keep it as array to document that i have materialized arrays or is there something more elegant by passing in Enumerable ??

Comment: @leora If passing an array is a requirement to calling your functions, then keep the array in the signature. Your callers would not have any flexibility about passing anything else, though. If you want to allow *some* additional flexibility, switch to `ICollection<MyObject>`: this will allow any collection or an array, and stop the warning.